# Logging in React

Tags: logs, react

I want to add logs to my React app. My requirements are:

1. persistent logging. Could be either locally in a file, and should have an option to log to a DB.
2. Should be able to log different levels (warnings, errors, info etc.)
3. App exception logging.

I've heard about Sentry and Winston which might fit, but I'm not sure. It's not a problem using both if required if they complement each other.

What logging framework would you recommend? If Winston and Sentry are indeed your recommendations, what are the use cases for both?